# PostgreSQL : it is possible to restore only Large Object with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

We have a simple table `my_table` like :

```
id (int) -> primary key
object_id (Large Object)
```

Unfortunately, a contractor of us have run `lo_unlink` on the IDs of the large objects from the column `object_id` of the table `my_table`.

The Large Object ID are still in the table, but the associated Large Objects not exist anymore :

```
ERROR:  large object 10268782 does not exist
SQL state: 42704
```

We do backup with `pg_dump` every night.

How we can restore only the Large Object with `pg_restore` ?

Indeed, we don't need to restore all the tables, even not the table with LOB ID (because the ID are still defined), but reload only the Large Object into the database from the dump.

The `pg_restore` has an option :

```
--data-only
Restore only the data, not the schema (data definitions). Table data, large objects, and sequence values are restored, if present in the archive.
```

but we don't want to restore table data or sequence values. Just large objects.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restore only the large objects from a dump that is *not* in plain text format, you can proceed as follows:

- create a "table of contants" file from the dump:

  ```bash
  pg_restore --list --file=tocfile dumpfile
  ```
- edit `tocfile` and remove all lines except the one that contains `BLOBS`, for example

  ```
  4353; 0 0 BLOBS - BLOBS
  ```
- now you can restore only the large objects:

  ```bash
  pg_restore --use-list=tocfile --dbname=proddb dumpfile
  ```

That will overwrite *all* large objects in the database. If you only want to restore certain large objects, there is no easy way. You can run the final `pg_restore` to write SQL statements to a file by using `--file=lobs.sql` instead of `--dbname=proddb`, which will create an SQL script with all large objects in it. You'd have to edit that file manually to extract the objects you want :^/